# Create CF-compliant NetCDF from ESRI Grid?

Tags: gdal, arcgis-10.2, netcdf

Been trying to make a CF-compliant netCDF file from an ESRI Grid. I want to serve it w/the THREDDS server. Been using `gdal_translate`. I know the `netcdf` output option is definitely not CF compliant, so I've been using the `GMT` output option. This doesn't seem to be functioning properly w/in THREDDS, so I'm guessing that's not CF-compliant either.

As an aside, I'm trying to validate the CF-compliance of my GMT-type netcdf. Been waiting for a really long time for it to load up to http://puma.nerc.ac.uk/cgi-bin/cf-checker.pl. In the meantime, trying to set up the cf-checker.py script but dependencies on deprecated CDAT libraries is making that a pain.

Anybody got a cleaner way to do this?

---EDIT---

ncdump of my GMT-conforming NetCDF file. Seems odd that I have "x_range" and "y_range" but no "x" or "y". Also seems like I'm providing almost no metadata via this process--making CF compliance seem unlikely to me...

```
netcdf E:/software/apache-tomcat-6.0.39/content/thredds/public/wk_gmt/wk_awc/al.nc {
  dimensions:
    side = 2;
    xysize = 1902411900;
  variables:
    double x_range(side=2);
      :units = "meters";

    double y_range(side=2);
      :units = "meters";

    double z_range(side=2);
      :units = "meters";

    double spacing(side=2);

    int dimension(side=2);

    float z(xysize=1902411900);
      :scale_factor = 1.0; // double
      :add_offset = 0.0; // double
      :node_offset = 1; // int

  // global attributes:
  :title = "";
  :source = "";
}
```

---EDIT # 2---

Just a little more content to show the difference in the NetCDF files produced by gdal vs. ESRI based on comment from @mdsumner. I totally agree that gdal should be doing it right. Quite possible I'm not using the tool correctly (`gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of NetCDF ${in} ${out}` in my shell script, fwiw).

As @signell notes below, the ESRI output ain't perfect, but it seems closer to CF compliance...the following is the ncdump of the file created from a *.nc from the same ESRI Grid. This file was created using ESRI's `Raster to NetCDF`.

```
netcdf E:/software/apache-tomcat-6.0.39/content/thredds/public/wk_esri/wk_awc/al.nc {
  dimensions:
    x = 11334;
    y = 18650;
  variables:
    double x(x=11334);
      :long_name = "x coordinate of projection";
      :standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate";
      :units = "Meter";

    double y(y=18650);
      :long_name = "y coordinate of projection";
      :standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate";
      :units = "Meter";

    float awc(y=18650, x=11334);
      :long_name = "awc";
      :esri_pe_string = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_Albers\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Albers\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-96.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",29.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",45.5],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",23.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";
      :coordinates = "x y";
      :grid_mapping = "albers_conical_equal_area";
      :units = "Meter";
      :missing_value = -3.4028235E38f; // float

    int albers_conical_equal_area;
      :grid_mapping_name = "albers_conical_equal_area";
      :longitude_of_central_meridian = -96.0; // double
      :latitude_of_projection_origin = 23.0; // double
      :false_easting = 0.0; // double
      :false_northing = 0.0; // double
      :standard_parallel = 29.5, 45.5; // double

  // global attributes:
  :Conventions = "CF-1.0";
  :Source_Software = "Esri ArcGIS";
}
```

Comment: GMT is a really weird variant that drops the array dims and requires the client to reinstate it, I doubt that it's what you want

Comment: +1 @mdsumner for confirming that. Thanks. It was a guess based on a 6-year old post to another wikispace. Desperate measure at best!

Comment: I think you should demonstrate your evidence for this and what version of GDAL you are using and how you use it, " I know the netcdf output option is definitely not CF compliant" - it's not something I've looked at in detail but a lot of work has been done to improve NetCDF in GDAL in the last few years.

Comment: although I'm no expert, I felt the ncdump that I edited into the question earlier shows at least one major issue, which is that there are no "x" and "y" variables. More heuristically, THREDDS wasn't able to produce a usable WMS with that. I'll also include the ncdump of file created using `Raster to NetCDF` for comparison.

Comment: Please include the GDAL version.

Comment: that's what the 1st edit includes.

Comment: GDAL version 1.9.2 works perfectly when you use `-of netCDF`, generating not only the coordinate variables `x` and `y`, but also the CF `grid_mapping` variable complete with ellipsoid information `semi_major_axis` and `inverse_flattening`.

Comment: ah. I misunderstood @mdsumner's question. I ran GDAL 1.7.3, which appears to be my issue given RichSignell's post.

Comment: Not sure I was born when that version came out

Comment: ouch, but true.  Guess I installed that around the time dirt came into existence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcGIS 10.1, I just tried converting two rasters (geographic and albers) using `ArcToolbox=>Multidimensional Tools=>Raster to NetCDF` and the resulting files seem to be CF-Compliant -- they work just fine with the Unidata THREDDS Data Server.

Try drilling down to the OPeNDAP data links or Godiva2 viewer links here:
http://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/catalog/usgs/data2/rsignell/data/bathy/arc_netcdf/catalog.html
to see these two netCDF files.

And of course you can just download them using the HTTPServer links.

Here's what the geographic file looks like in [Unidata's Tools-UI](ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/netcdf-java/v4.3/toolsUI-4.3.jar): 
 [image]

But oh no, here's what the Albers file looks like:[image]

Things don't look good.  The topography is not plotting in the right location -- it's shifted by quite a bit.

Taking a look at the ArcGIS 10.1-produced NetCDF file, we see that there is no ellipsoid information in the `grid_mapping` variable, in this case, the variable `albers_conical_equal_area`:

```
netcdf dods://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/dodsC/usgs/data2/rsignell/data/bathy/arc_netcdf/traster_albers.nc {
  dimensions:
    x = 1272;
    y = 1361;
  variables:
    double x(x=1272);
      :long_name = "x coordinate of projection";
      :standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate";
      :units = "Meter";

    double y(y=1361);
      :long_name = "y coordinate of projection";
      :standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate";
      :units = "Meter";

    int albers_conical_equal_area;
      :grid_mapping_name = "albers_conical_equal_area";
      :longitude_of_central_meridian = -96.0; // double
      :latitude_of_projection_origin = 23.0; // double
      :false_easting = 0.0; // double
      :false_northing = 0.0; // double
      :standard_parallel = 29.5, 45.5; // double

    float traster_View_ProjectRaster(y=1361, x=1272);
      :_CoordinateAxes = "x y y x ";
      :long_name = "traster_View_ProjectRaster";
      :esri_pe_string = "PROJCS[\"USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Albers\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-96.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",29.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",45.5],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",23.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";
      :coordinates = "x y";
      :grid_mapping = "albers_conical_equal_area";
      :units = "Meter";
      :missing_value = -3.4028235E38f; // float

  // global attributes:
  :Conventions = "CF-1.0";
  :Source_Software = "Esri ArcGIS";
}
```

The CF Conventions specify that the ellipsoid representation should be encoded using `semi_major_axis` and (`semi_minor_axis` or `inverse_flattening`).  Since `semi_major_axis` and `inverse_flattening` values are right there in the `esri_pe_string` attribute, we can fix this file up using NcML thusly:

```
<netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2"
  location="traster_albers.nc">
<variable name="albers_conical_equal_area">
    <attribute name="semi_major_axis" type="double" value="6378137.0"/>
    <attribute name="inverse_flattening" type="double" value="298.257222101"/>
</variable>
</netcdf>
```

If we try plotting again,  it now looks correct:
[image]

This should be easy for ESRI to fix because all they have to do is pull the ellipsoid values out of the esri_pe_string.   The resulting CF-Compliant file would then look like this:

```
netcdf dods://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/dodsC/usgs/data2/rsignell/data/bathy/arc_netcdf/traster_albers_fixed2.ncml {
  dimensions:
    x = 1272;
    y = 1361;
  variables:
    double x(x=1272);
      :long_name = "x coordinate of projection";
      :standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate";
      :units = "Meter";

    double y(y=1361);
      :long_name = "y coordinate of projection";
      :standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate";
      :units = "Meter";

    int albers_conical_equal_area;
      :grid_mapping_name = "albers_conical_equal_area";
      :longitude_of_central_meridian = -96.0; // double
      :latitude_of_projection_origin = 23.0; // double
      :false_easting = 0.0; // double
      :false_northing = 0.0; // double
      :standard_parallel = 29.5, 45.5; // double
      :semi_major_axis = 6378137.0; // double
      :inverse_flattening = 298.257222101; // double

    float traster_View_ProjectRaster(y=1361, x=1272);
      :_CoordinateAxes = "x y y x ";
      :long_name = "traster_View_ProjectRaster";
      :esri_pe_string = "PROJCS[\"USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Albers\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",0.0],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-96.0],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",29.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",45.5],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",23.0],UNIT[\"Meter\",1.0]]";
      :coordinates = "x y";
      :grid_mapping = "albers_conical_equal_area";
      :units = "Meter";
      :missing_value = -3.4028235E38f; // float

  // global attributes:
  :Conventions = "CF-1.0";
  :Source_Software = "Esri ArcGIS";
}
```

Comment: and extra +1 for the workaround that can be used until ESRI patches this tool!

Comment: Thanks Rich, great answer. Hopefully something that can be fixed in the next release.